# `lando artisan` command returns a weird error

Tags: php, laravel, lando

If you've worked with Laravel and Lando together, you probably know that Lando gives you its own `artisan` shortcut. So instead of having to run `lando php artisan ...`, you can run `lando artisan ...`.

However, when I do that, I get this error:

```
Could not open input file: /app/./../artisan
```

This forces me to have to run `lando php artisan` to run any artisan commands, and that does work fine. So far, this is all that's going wrong with my project in Lando. Everything else is running smoothly.

Here's what my lando config looks like:

```yaml
name: laravel-project
recipe: laravel
config:
  php: '7.4'
  composer_version: '2.0.12'
  database: mysql:8.0
services:
  appserver:
    webroot: public
    xdebug: true
    config:
      php: .vscode/php.ini
  node:
    type: node:14
tooling:
  node:
    service: node
  yarn:
    service: node
```

Also, this does look a bit different from Lando's [sample config](https://docs.lando.dev/config/laravel.html#configuration) on their website. This is because I was trying to configure xdebug according to their ["Using Lando with VSCode"](https://docs.lando.dev/guides/lando-with-vscode.html#getting-started) instructions (see Lando rc.2+ version).

Appreciate any help figuring this weird issue out. It's not debilitating, but it does get in the way when I forget the workaround.

---

Other notes:

- "webroot" is set to "public" because that's where the public-facing directory is for a Laravel app. The example [Lando config for Laravel](https://docs.lando.dev/config/laravel.html#configuration) has this part wrong and it causes the project root to be visible to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I moved the `webroot` key back under the top-level `config`. Not sure what the difference is, but as long as it works... I guess the only thing I really need to specify in the `appserver` service is the Xdebug settings.

```yaml
name: laravel-project
recipe: laravel
config:
  php: '7.4'
  composer_version: '2.0.12'
  webroot: public
  database: mysql:8.0
services:
  appserver:
    xdebug: true
    config:
      php: .vscode/php.ini
  node:
    type: node:14
tooling:
  node:
    service: node
  yarn:
    service: node
```